# While Sync the sitecore 10 items using docker and container with command line - "dotnet sitecore ser pull" getting the error

Tags: docker, containers, sitecore

Unhandled exception: System.Exception: Unhandled exception ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.TreeCongruencyCommandBuilder.GenerateCommands(TreeSpec subtree, ITreeDataStore sourceDataStore, ITreeDataStore destinationDataStore, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.TreeSyncOperation.DiscoverCommands(TreeSpec subtree, TreeCongruencyCommandBuilder commandBuilder, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.TreeSyncOperation.DiscoverCommands(Boolean applyAllowedPushOperations, IEnumerable`1 subtrees, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.TreeSyncOperationExecutor.ExecuteTreeSyncOperation(TreeSyncOperation operation, Boolean whatIf, Boolean performValidation, SyncDirection direction, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Serialization.Tasks.SyncTask.Execute(SyncTaskOptions options)   at Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Serialization.Commands.SyncCommandBase.Handle(SyncTask task, SyncArgs args)   at Sitecore.Devex.Client.Cli.Extensibility.Subcommands.SubcommandBase`2.HandleInternal(TArgs args) in C:\BA\ca7111d945a16af4\src\Sitecore.Devex.Client.Cli.Extensibility\Subcommands\SubcommandBase.cs:line 75   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at Sitecore.Devex.Client.Cli.Extensibility.Subcommands.SubcommandBase`2.HandleExceptionMessageConsoleLogging(Exception exception, ILogger logger) in C:\BA\ca7111d945a16af4\src\Sitecore.Devex.Client.Cli.Extensibility\Subcommands\SubcommandBase.cs:line 120   at Sitecore.Devex.Client.Cli.Extensibility.Subcommands.SubcommandBase`2.HandleInternal(TArgs args) in C:\BA\ca7111d945a16af4\src\Sitecore.Devex.Client.Cli.Extensibility\Subcommands\SubcommandBase.cs:line 81   at System.CommandLine.Invocation.CommandHandler.GetResultCodeAsync(Object value, InvocationContext context)   at System.CommandLine.Invocation.ModelBindingCommandHandler.InvokeAsync(InvocationContext context)   at System.CommandLine.Invocation.InvocationPipeline.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<b__20_0>d.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass24_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<b__21_0>d.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<b__19_0>d.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<b__11_0>d.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<b__10_0>d.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()

In visual studio 2022 on project solution I opened the terminal and tried to execute the command "dotnet sitecore ser pull" and facing the issue.